# Zero all negative elements in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have an array of negative and positive numbers, how can I make all negative numbers become zero and remain all positive numbers in a simple way (without iterating over it with multiple for loops as the array is multi dimensional)? My idea was:

```
a = np.array(...) # any random array
a = 0 if a < 0 else a
```

But it doesn't work :(

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, -3, -2, 5, -1])
>>> a[a<0] = 0
>>> a
>>> [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `np.where`

```
a=np.array([1,2,3,-1,2,-4])
a=np.where(a>0, a, 0)
```

Output:

```
a
[1 2 3 0 2 0]
```